# binary search not working using vectors

Tags: c++, c++11

i am having problem with my binary search function. basically the aim is just want to check if zero is in the vector or not. but it doesnt return the right result. here is the code. Can any body figure out what am i doing wrong?

```
bool RecursiveBinarySearch::binarySearch(std::vector<int> &input, int left, int right)
{
    int mid_number;
    int odd_even = (right - left)%2;
    if(odd_even == 0)
    {
        mid_number = (right-left)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        mid_number = (((right-left)+1)/2)-1;
    }

    if(right>=left)
    {
        if(input.at(mid_number)==0)
        {
             return true; //mid_number
        }
        else if(input.at(mid_number)>0)
        {
            return binarySearch(input, left, mid_number-1);
        }
        else
        {
            return binarySearch(input, mid_number+1, right);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false; //-1 return
    }
}
```

input: 1 2 3 4 0 it should return true but return 0
input: 1 0 should return true, but returns false.

Comment: Please at least post the actual test case when it does not work.

Comment: Why will someone complicate a binary search algorithm like this.. you have pointlessly complicated your algorithm.. and now you are confused .. better grab a text book and read about binary search

Comment: Aside: all that stuff with `odd_even` doesn't do anything; both cases result in `(right - left)/2`.

Comment: "odd_even" is a confusing name - it's impossible to guess whether the variable is intended to indicate oddness or evenness.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce, works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c64a2b8df8a1a314)

Comment: "*Can any body figure out what am i doing wrong?*" - You are trying to reimplement something that is already in standard. And you are not abiding this rule: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*"

Comment: @Hurkyl what is the number of elements is even. it is for that?

Comment: `mid_number = left + (right-left)/2` ?

Comment: "1 2 3 4 0" is **not a valid sequence for a binary search!** It needs to be **sorted** in order to work.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Try `binarySearch({ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 0, 8)`.

Comment: @Barry you're doing the OPs job presenting that case at this point.

Comment: i guess no question asked is stupid. but i totally forgot here it has to be sorted. i m so sorry guys. I totally forgot..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `mid_number` is wrong.

Consider `binarySearch(arr, 5, 11)`. You are setting `mid_number` to 3. But 3 isn't in the range from `[5,11)`. You need to add `left` to `mid_number`.